# Vue js is it ok to register all components globally?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, frontend, vue-component

Is it ok/good practice to register all components globally?

**Reason**

- to avoid doing of imports of components manually when other components needed them.
- a bit annoyed seeing component with lots of import when the app gets bigger.

Are there any downside of this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You generally shouldn't register a component globally if you aren't going to use it frequently throughout your application. Quoting [the docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Local-Registration) ...

> Global registration often isn’t ideal. For example, if you’re using a
> build system like Webpack, globally registering all components means
> that even if you stop using a component, it could still be included in
> your final build. This unnecessarily increases the amount of
> JavaScript your users have to download.

Comment: Thanks, now I have a better understanding about Vue components when and when not to register them globally. :)